# Set Map Bounds with different padding

Tags: android, google-maps, padding, bounds

I want to know if ther is any way of set different padding from each site of the Device for Google maps bounds.

Because I have an mpview witch match the whole activity, but I have a MapOverlay (some Text inside a linerar Layout with non transulent background) on the bottom 1/3 off the screen.

And now i want to zoom in by using map bounds. But it should have more padding from the bottom so it didn't get behind my mapOverlay.

I use this code with the padding of 120.

```
final com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds.Builder bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
bounds.include(pref.getSavedLatLng());
bounds.include(currentLatLng);
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds.build(), 120));
```

Is there any way of setting different paddings, or other solution for this problem?

Thank you for helping and sorry for my english.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is an older question and maybe the asker found the solution but here it is for anyone who faces same problem in future. Set the individual padding using
 `googleMap.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom)` 
and then use
 `googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds.build(), 0))`
Don't forget to set the paddings back to 0 (or whatever they were before) after you are done. Because unlike `newLatLngBounds()`, the paddings set by `setPadding()` are permanent.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, because it will also add a padding to the Google logo in the bottom left corner so that it floats around on the map.

Comment: This works but the Google icon will be come to middle of the screen!

Comment: @LakpriyaSenevirathna just use below 3 lines.

googleMap.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom)
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds.build(), 0))
googleMap.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)

You will not even notice the google icon moving.

Comment: Hackish, but works in flutter as well.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old but for more informations please check [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views).

If the bound is supposed to be applied for a specific action, setting the map padding may not be a good solution cause it's permanent.

apply a padding of 100 and above to see the effect in your map. Bellow is a simple example.

```
final int MAP_BOUND_PADDING = 180;  /* In dp */  
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for (LatLng latLng : listLatLng) { //listLatLngis a list of latLng to bound. You can put two if you want. 
    builder.include(latLng);
}
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, MAP_BOUND_PADDING);
mMap.animateCamera(cu);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be used but here we have small animation issue!

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50), new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(-1));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }
            });
```